# Reload Images AND Thumbnails in jssor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I am trying to have more than one jssor album without loading another page / reloading the page while still keeping the different albums separate from each other.

In the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896066/change-slide-set-in-jssor-slider) question the [Nested Slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html) is recommended, however I still want to use Thumbnails in each of the albums. Also I would prefer to let the user switch the shown album by a jquery dropdown menu instead of the solution of the Nested Slider.

Is there any way to change and reload thumbnails during runtime like it is possible with images?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2 separate sliders in one page. One is shown and another is hidden.

When an user choose category from dropdown menu, you can switch slider to show.

You can have 2 or more sliders, and show only one at a time.

```
function ShowHideSlider(category) {
    if(category == "cate1") {
        $("#slider1_container").show();
        //and hide all other sliders
    }
    else if(category = "cate2") {
        $("#slider2_container").show();
        //and hide all other sliders
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a demo link or a small code snippet?

Or is this just about having two sliders in the html container and setting them to hidden / not hidden?

And is this feature limited to 2 sliders?