# Jssor thumbnail Corner Case Issue

Tags: jssor

I have implemented the jssor slider and it mostly works but I discovered a corner case that has me puzzled.

The following variables are involved $StartIndex, $Cols, and $Align.

When $StartIndex is zero, everything works correctly.
When the number of images is greater than $Cols, everything works correctly.
By that, I mean that all images are displayed and the current image is centered in the thumb display as set by $Align.

When the number of images is less than or EQUAL to $Cols and $StartIndex is not zero, some of the thumbs are hidden off to the left - as if $Align was set to zero.The thumbs can be dragged into position and everything works from then on, but that's obviously not what I want. Here is the code:

```
    var options = {
    $AutoPlay: false,
    $AutoPlayInterval: 4500,
    $PauseOnHover: 3, //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

    $DragOrientation: 3,
    $Loop: false,
    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
    $SlideDuration: 300,
    $FillMode: 1,
    $LazyLoading: 5,
    $StartIndex: 3,

    $SlideshowOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$, 
        $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,
        $TransitionsOrder: 1,
        $ShowLink: true
    },
    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
        $ChanceToShow: 2
    },
    $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
        $ChanceToShow: 2,
        $ActionMode: 1,
        $SpacingX: 10,
        $Cols: 8,
        $Align: 470
    }
};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
```

Comment: Thanks. Otherwise working great. Would like a method to dynamically add and delete images though.

Comment: Slide count is fixed after the slider is initialized, but you can alter anything in each slide. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870482/jssor-slider-how-to-reload-refresh-the-slider-to-show-new-images

Comment: Thanks. Were you by any chance able to replicate the issue with the thumbs starting off hidden?

Comment: Yes, I got the problem. I will update you when I get it fixed.

Comment: Is the problem by any chance fixed?

Comment: Will work on it soon.

Comment: I have just get it fixed.

Comment: Awesome! Where should I look for the update?

Comment: http://www.jssor.com/download.html

Comment: I downloaded the new code, but when I replaced jssor.slider.mini.js with the new version, the thumbnails all went blank. I made no other changes. Switching back, restored everything, but still with the original problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: please send me your work or leave an url.

Comment: Switching from src2 to src fixed the problem but the loading is now very slow since it appears that lazy loading is no longer working.

Comment: I got the problem. Let me check it out.